# Batch processing error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, error, batch

I get a Python error when I run any plugins as batch processing in QGIS 3.6.3. The problem does not solve if I change layers. Any idea how to solve it?

The error I get is:

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\BatchAlgorithmDialog.py", line 88, in runAlgorithm
              parameters[param.name()] = wrapper.parameterValue()
             AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parameterValue'
```

Comment: In detail, I have more raster files and a multipolygon shapefile with the same CRS. I want to extract the mean of the raster values corresponding to each polyon. I tried to use the  'Zonal statistics' plugin as batch processing, but I get that error. However the plugin works if I calculate the mean one by one (without using the batch processing). I have also tried to change layers or to use other plugins but the issue persists. It seems there is a problem only with the batch processing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem just downloading QGIS 3.10!